# Compare GPS points to the current location

Tags: iphone, events, gps, cllocation

I am  using the instance method distanceFromLocation in order to compare my new location with const defined locations

I am giving CLLocation *bonuslocation an instant value which is one of the  gps points i am interested in and then i compare it to the new location
if the distance is less than 20m from the point an audio file is played.

While this is working perfectly for one location it does not work at all
if i add locally into the updatelocationmanager function more than one..

The code:

```
CLLocation *bonuslocation = [.....]
CLLocationDistance distancea = [bonuslocation distanceFromLocation newlocation]
if (distancea <= 20)
{
//play an audio
}
```

Can i have some advice on how to do it for 10 gps points????

Today is my Birthday can you see that as a birthday present??
Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put it in a loop? Or just run the comparison on 10 locations? What exactly is it that isn't working?

**EDIT:**

You never mentioned where you're getting your other locations, so let's assume you make them somehow and store them in an array...

```
NSArray *locationArray;
```

I gathered from your comment that you have different sounds for each location? A simple way would be to store the sounds in a second array...

```
NSArray *soundsArray;
```

Then you can do the following in your locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation { 

    for(int i=0; i<[locationArray count]; i++){
        CLLocation *location = (CLLocation *)[locationArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if([newLocation distanceFromLocation:location] < 20.0){
            //perform some action e.g.
            //play sound at [soundArray objectAtIndex:i]
        }
    }
}
```

Although I don't recommend simply playing a sound, as this simple logic will cause the sound to be played once for every location within the threshold all at the same time.

Comment: When i initialize the CLLOcation *bonuslocation it keeps only one of the values i declare so if i say CLLocation *differentlocation it executes that part of code but not the one for bonus location.. is that clear??

Comment: What if i make a for(i=0; i=10; i++) and inside put a switch : case do you think it will be fine??

Comment: Please see the edits to my answer. Why would you need the switch statement? Are you performing a different action for each location?